# Set cookie with expires in TestClient

Tags: cookies, fastapi

I need to set a cookie in my TestClient with a max_age or expires.

So far I have:

```py
cookies = test_client.cookies
cookies.set(cookie_key, str(cookie_value), path=path)
test_client.cookies = cookies
```

where `test_client` is of type `fastapi.testclient.TestClient`.  The `set` method does not accept `expires` or `max_age`.

Comment: I've left a [feature request](https://github.com/encode/httpx/discussions/2962) on `httpx`

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping there's a better, but for now, here's a workaround:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from http.cookiejar import Cookie
from httpx import Cookies

def _set_httpx_cookies(cookies: Cookies,
                       name: str,
                       value: str,
                       domain: str = '',
                       path: str = '/',
                       max_age: int | None = None) -> None:
    """Hack to set cookies in `httpx` with `max_age`.

    `httpx` doesn't support max_age.  Remove this hack if that changes
    (https://github.com/encode/httpx/discussions/2962).
    """
    if max_age is None:
        expires = None
    else:
        expires_datetime = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=max_age)
        expires = expires_datetime.timestamp()

    # The remainder is from `httpx`, except that I pass in `expires` instead of `None`.
    # (https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/cc206cf2dad42600479962ac1daaa44675cfaf56/httpx/_models.py#L1056-L1076)
    kwargs = {
        'version': 0,
        'name': name,
        'value': value,
        'port': None,
        'port_specified': False,
        'domain': domain,
        'domain_specified': bool(domain),
        'domain_initial_dot': domain.startswith('.'),
        'path': path,
        'path_specified': bool(path),
        'secure': False,
        'expires': expires,
        'discard': True,
        'comment': None,
        'comment_url': None,
        'rest': {
            'HttpOnly': None
        },
        'rfc2109': False,
    }
    cookie = Cookie(**kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    cookies.jar.set_cookie(cookie)
```